# Unable to locate imageview for uploading to parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

**Edit: Solved.**

I'm trying to upload an image to parse that has been selected from the phone's gallery. However I cannot seem to locate the imageview as it returns null. I think this page: [Saving images to Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295154/saving-images-to-parse) has a similar question to what I'm asking but there is no answer to it.

Fragment class:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            img = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            // Locate the image (error is here)
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), img);
            // Convert it to byte
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();


            //byte[] image = img.getContext().toString().getBytes();

            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img);

            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("image.jpg", image);
            file.saveInBackground();
            ParseObject familyTree = new ParseObject("FamilyTree");
            familyTree.put("image", file);
            familyTree.put("name", etName.getText().toString());
            familyTree.put("relation", etRelation.getText().toString());
            familyTree.saveInBackground();
            Toast.makeText(FamilyTreeFragment2.this.getActivity(), "Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FamilyTreeFragment2()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution.

Replaced

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), img);
```

with

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```